# I would like to manipulate columns using codecs

Tags: python

I am trying to extract information from a compressed file. 
I used this code:

```
import codecs
!gunzip pagecounts-20150501-000000.gz
log = codecs.open('pagecounts-20150501-000000', 'r')
lines = log.readlines(1)
print(lines)
```

However it gives me only the first letter in the file.  The file has actually 4 columns, but I would like to store the first two columns using a dataframe or any other structure for massive data (almost 186328237 lines).

Answer (score 1):

You're only asking for the first character in the first line:

```
lines = log.readlines(1)
```

You're only passing a '1' to `readlines`' [`read()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=readlines#codecs.StreamReader.read) - if you want to read more than that, change that value, or you could use the `readline()` method to read a single line at a time.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=readlines#codecs.StreamReader.readlines):

> **readlines**([*sizehint*[, *keepends*]]) Read all lines available on the
>   input stream and return them as a list of lines.
>
> Line-endings are implemented using the codec’s decoder method and are
>   included in the list entries if keepends is true.
>
> *sizehint*, if given, is passed as the size argument to the stream’s
>   read() method.

To read the first line, try:

```
lines = log.readline()
```

Comment: I have tried using readline(1) instead of readlines(1):                                        *readline(1) gives mes back the first letter of the file

Comment: There are 99 letters in the first line.

Comment: NB passing 1 to `readline()` is passing the same size argument to `read()` as `readlines()` does - read the docs link.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?

Comment: Was this answer helpful, if so, please feel free to accept it. If you found a different solution, please post/accept it yourself, to help others with a similar issue in future.